# Read txt file real time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

I would like to know if there is some way to read a .txt file from Javascript in real-time?
I have a log file that updates every few seconds. I want to parse some data from that log file as it updates and display it in a html.
Can I do this live?
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Where is that log file stored?

Comment: little known bit of coolness: if the log file is on your computer, you can use an <input type=file> to upload it to js. then, every time you use a new FileReader() on it, it will re-load a fresh copy from the disk, including any changes that were made after clicking the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the file is somewhere publicly accessible, you can have a javascript function which makes an AJAX request every few seconds to read the file. Something like the following:

```
function getLog() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'logfile.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            $("#containerDiv").text(text);
            setTimeout(getLog, 30000); // refresh every 30 seconds
        }
    })
}

getLog();
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! The file has about 16 mb... would that be a problem? Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, 16Mb is huge and would be a problem. You should try and limit the data requested to somewhere in the region of 500k maximum.

Comment: And when ajax reads it can the server add some new lines in it?

Comment: You can't make AJAX calls to local files, unless you have permitted the browser to do so.

Comment: Maybe a better way would be to write a sever-side script that returns only the parts of the logfile that have been added. That way you restrict the file size to the absolutely needed minimum.

Comment: @pbibergal the URL is specified is for demonstration, obviously the OP would need to amend this

Comment: @Nirazul Good idea. That would be a much better implementation. All it would require once the script is written is to change the URL of the request to the server-side script, instead of the logfile directly.

Comment: you can use an HTP Range header to grab the end of the file by specifying a negative amount.

Comment: The first valueable answer I got in one hor of search.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't read/write a file with Javascript, cause it would be a terrible security issue.

But, in your case, you can use some Ajax calls to a server-side script.

Comment: Indeed it is possible. See [this draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) @W3C. And have a look at [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).